# SQL Session Syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I am using a GridView in Visual studio and adding custom SQL query to it.

```
SELECT 
    [Type], [YogaType], [ReservationTime], [ReservationDate], 
    [SpacesLeft], [Cancelled], [SessionID] 
FROM 
    [Reservation] 
WHERE 
    (([CustomerID] = ?) 
     AND ([ReservationDate] > #?#) 
     OR ([ReservationDate] = #?# AND ([ReservationTime] > #?#)))
```

The information that fills out the quote marks comes from session. And the following error comes up when I try to test it.

> Syntax error in date in query expression '(([CustomerID] = ?) AND ([ReservationDate] > #?#) OR ([ReservationDate] = #?# AND ([ReservationTime] > #?#))'.

Any ideas what is going wrong? I cannot debug the ASPX page, can't set breaking point already tried. I am using a MS Access database

Comment: First thing to try is to remove the # around the dates parameters placeholders. That rules doesn't apply when you use parameters. Then you should show the code that builds the parameter collection and explain what datatype you pass to these parameters

Comment: Customer ID is integer, and Date and Time are passed as DateTime

Comment: Could you add to your question the effective code used? For example if you use AddWithValue then there are a lot of problems there.

Comment: You should show how you make the call to the db. I thought that `@` is used to define a parameter in queries, for example, `@CustomerID`

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk that's not the case with OleDb albeit Access supports that syntax

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure it out, using alot of testing in access and the query builder this is the SQL query that works:

```
SELECT [Type], [YogaType], [ReservationDate], [ReservationTime], [SpacesLeft], [Cancelled], [SessionID] FROM [Reservation] WHERE (([CustomerID] = ?) AND ([ReservationDate] > ?) OR ([ReservationDate] = ? AND ([ReservationTime] > ?)));
```